# Query to match people with ID

Tags: sql, join

Let's suppose we have 2 tables. 
First is for some ORDER: salesperson_id, customer_id, date, price... etc
Second is for people record PERSON: person_id, name, mail... etc

I need to select the order with both customer and salesperson names. 
So row of records looks like this

```
order.order_id, order.date, name (for customer), name (for salesperson)
```

I don't want to display ids for people, only names.

I cannot join with the PERSON table twice, so, my question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can - join the `person` table twice but with different alias names.

```
select o.order_id, o.date, 
       c.name as customer, 
       s.name as sales_person
from order_table o
left join person_table c on c.id = o.customer_id
left join person_table s on s.id = o.salesperson_id
```

Comment: Couldn't you join once and do an OR? Like...left join person_table p on p.id = o.customer_id or p.id = o.salesperoson_id.  Or something along the lines of that?  Would it just lower performance?

Comment: No, this is the way you do it. And the performance should not be an issue since you join on primary keys.